# Processing, Null Pointer exception in Array

Tags: arrays, null, processing

I'm trying to write a sort of boggle program. I have succeeded in generating some random text on the screen. Now I want to link each section of the grid to a letter. The coordinates are off atm but the problem is that when I clicked in the region X <= 50; Y <= 50 I get a null value, whilst the elements of my array are being constantly drawn so it can't be empty can it?

```
boolean clicked = false;
boolean Gen = true;
void setup() {
size(1000,1000);
textSize(64);
textAlign(CENTER);

}
void draw() {
 String [] Storage = new String[17];  
 int x1 = 5;
 int x2 = 5;
 int x3 = 5;
 int x4 = 5;


 if(Gen) {
background(#AFA3A3);
// Loop for Storing
for(int i = 0; i < 17; i = i+1) {
String a;
a = genereren();
Storage[i]=a;
}
//Loop for Reading
//First Row
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j = j+1) {
text(Storage[j], 80+(x1*10), 125);
x1 = x1 +12;
}
//Second Row
for(int k = 4; k < 8; k = k+1) {
text(Storage[k], 80+(x2*10), 250); 
x2 = x2 +12;
}
//Thrid Row
for(int c = 8; c < 12; c = c+1) {
text(Storage[c], 80+(x3*10), 375); 
x3 = x3 +12;
}
//Fourth Row
for(int o = 12; o < 16; o = o+1) {
text(Storage[o], 80+(x4*10), 500); 
x4 = x4 +12;
}
 }
Gen = false;
  for(int i=50; i<500;i=i+125){
    noFill();
    strokeWeight(5);
    rect(i,50,125,125);
    rect(i,175,125,125);
    rect(i,300,125,125);
    rect(i,425,125,125);
  }
if(clicked==true && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY <= 50) {
text(Storage[1], 500,500);  
}
Reset();
}
//draw
public String genereren() {
String alfabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
float r = random(24);
if(r < 1) {
  r = r+1;
}
int d = int(r);
String EersteLetter;
EersteLetter = alfabet.substring(d-1,d);
return EersteLetter;
}
public void Store() {

}
public void mouseClicked() {
  clicked = true;
}
public void Reset() {
  clicked = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you using any specific programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When posting code, please use sane formatting and standard naming conventions (Storage should be storage, etc).

Anyway, you're initializing your Storage variable inside your draw function, which means you're creating a new empty array 60 times a second. However, you only populate that array with values if Gen is true, which only happens the very first time draw() is called.

This means that in later calls to the draw() function, Storage is blank, which means it contains all null values. Then when you click in the upper-left corner, it's passing a null value into the text() function, which causes the NPE.

Most Processing sketches have a call to background() as the first line in the draw() function. Add that and you'll see that you aren't actually filling the array in subsequent calls to the draw() function. You probably want to populate it in the setup() function and then draw it every time draw() is called.

Comment: Thanks! It worked out, I'm sorry or the bad format it won't happen again.